# C# SqlCommand syntax for this SQL command

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

I am trying to turn this SQL example command into a C # `SqlCommand`:

```
if not exists (select column_name
               from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
               where table_name = 'TotalHeals'
                 and column_name = '"+Healee+"')
    alter table TotalHeals add +Healee+ int
```

What I have so far

```
// TO DO check to see if column exists instead of throwing error
cmd2 = new SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE TotalHeals ADD " + Healee + " INT",openCon);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am completely lost how to code the if not exists statement. Any help?

Comment: I am dynamically adding columns on the fly and do not want to just catch the exception when the column already exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute your first select query to check whether the column exist like this

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from
                     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
                     where
                     table_name = 'TotalHeals'
                     and column_name = '"+Healee+"',openCon);
int output=Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

if (output>0)
 // column already present....handle that case..
else
//alter your table to add the column
```

Comment: I am throwing a Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll on the int output=Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); line

Comment: are you doing select count(*) ?

Comment: Caught your code mid edit... testing the updated version

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I had to change this `'"+Healee+"'",openCon);`